# Jenkinsfile with email in loop fails on first iteration

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Latest Jenkins used.

edit: pastebin of full Java exception - https://pastebin.com/zZDNj18E

Goal: loop through all nodes, check for offline, email alert for each offline node.
(tried emailext alerts as well, could not  use "offline")

Failed: My jenkinsfile runs perfectly with no email.
With email in the for loop or separately defined in a function, the job crashes **after** the first email is sent.

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline an exception which occurred:     in field hudson.model.Slave.launcher    in object hudson.slaves.DumbSlave@ae938e61 .... and many more
```

My jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent{
    label  'master'
  }

  options {
        // Enable timestamps in log
        timestamps()
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timeout(time: 4, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
  stages {
        stage('Monitor') {
            steps{
              script{
                  def offlineSlaves = []

                  for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
                        def thisSlave = aSlave.name
                        echo 'Name: ' + thisSlave + ' is being checked.'
                        if ( aSlave.getComputer().isOffline().toString() == 'true') {
                            slaveState = 'OFFLINE'
                            echo 'Name: ' + thisSlave + ' is ' + slaveState + ' !'
                            emailext (
                              mimeType: 'text/html',
                              body: "${env.JOB_NAME} found an OFFLINE node: ${name}  ",
                              subject: "Jenkins ERROR: Build Node ${name} is OFFLINE " ,
                              to: 'jfisher@xxx')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    post {
        failure {
            emailext (
                body: 'Monitor Nodes Jenkins Job failed !',
                presendScript: '$DEFAULT_PRESEND_SCRIPT',
                recipientProviders: [requestor(),culprits()],
                subject: 'Monitor Nodes Jenkins Failed',
                to: 'jfisher@intouchhealth.com')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, could you please attach the whole stack trace for the exception thrown?

Comment: added pastebin above, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code is the `getComputer()` part. In the pipeline you should only use Serializable and the `SlaveComputer` returned from `getComputer()` isn't.

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html

What you should do is move this part to a function annotated with NonCPS

```
       @NonCPS
       def shallTrigger() {
              for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
                    def thisSlave = aSlave.name
                    echo 'Name: ' + thisSlave + ' is being checked.'
                    if ( aSlave.getComputer().isOffline().toString() == 'true') {
                        slaveState = 'OFFLINE'
                        echo 'Name: ' + thisSlave + ' is ' + slaveState + ' !'
                        emailext (
                          mimeType: 'text/html',
                          body: "${env.JOB_NAME} found an OFFLINE node: ${name}  ",
                          subject: "Jenkins ERROR: Build Node ${name} is OFFLINE " ,
                          to: 'jfisher@xxx')
                    }
              }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved to the function, placed outside the pipeline brackets, as directed. When I run the job, I get  errors which look like they might be related to a need for approval of an in-process script approval, but none is offered under Manage Jenkins-> in-process etc  but, when I comment out the emailext  part the loop works fine ( as indeed it did before)....

Comment: This solved the question, plus the realization that **emailext only runs once and then ends the job** no matter what. So I saved a list of offline nodes and sent that out in one email.